# Capture anything that's before a known pattern that may not be here

Tags: python, regex

Given those example strings :

```
str_1 = 'This will be captured (unwanted static pattern)'
str_2 = 'This wil also be captured'
```

How would I set a regular expression that would output :

```
out_1 = 'This will be captured'
out_2 = 'This wil also be captured'
```

I have tried so far (using case insensitive flag) :

```
(.*)\s+(?:\(unwanted static pattern\))?$
```

But it won't capture the first group when the pattern isn't present.

My precise question is : how do we propagate a '*' '+' or '?' on a whole pattern

Comment: But wait a tic, what if there's more text following `\(unwanted static pattern\))?$`? Is that a consideration here?

Comment: No, it's not a consideration in that particular situation, hence the $ character at the end

Comment: Yea, I saw the $ and am surprised that no amount of scalability needed to be added in here. Whelp, it's your post. No problem by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the match to be the shortest possible. Change `(.*)` to `(.*?)`. You'll also want to move the `\s+` inside the optional suffix (otherwise you require the match to end before a nonempty sequence of whitespace).

Demo: https://ideone.com/195NIk

This may seem paradoxical, until you understand that we still mean "the shortest possible match *which will still permit the overall regex to match".* So when the optional suffix isn't there, we match up through the end; and when it's there, we prefer a match which doesn't run through to the end of the string.

Comment: But wait a tic, what if there's more text following `\(unwanted static pattern\))?$`? I have a dirty (not optimal) solution for that, but how would you go about solving that because mine is messy.

Comment: Not sure if that's well-defined. You mean match everything if the static string doesn't occur, and end before the static text if it does? It doesn't actually have to be static at all; just add `.*` at the end.

Comment: Yes indeed. I actually wanted you to add that into your response, because based on the criteria, I'm pretty sure that the OP is going to encounter something like that. Something like `This will be captured (unwanted static pattern) and more stuff follows`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there will be no parentheses in the first group, you can try `([^\(]*)(?:\s+\(unwanted static pattern\))?$`, and take care of the white space.